# Objection js: Can't update many to many relation with join table extra property. Says additional property is invalid

Tags: node.js, orm, knex.js, objection.js

Using ObjectionJS over knex over Postgres, I am unable to patch an extra property in the join table of a model that has a many to many relation with another model. Even while following and reading and rereading the docs I have not been able to update the property. Even though the documentation lists exactly the same I'm doing.

Basically I have a waitlist model, and that model may have many users, with a join table between those two that has a "rank" property that works like an index on a list.
I am trying to update this rank property, following the `$relatedQuery` approach provided in the docs

Tried several combinations of query methods, both static and instance; tried to fetch the model again for each request, tried to add the relation on both models instead of a single one (since I did not need the other model to be aware of the relation) up to no avail

For comparison, this is an excerpt of the content of the ObjectionJS documentation on extra props that can be found [here](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/recipes/extra-properties.html#join-table-extra-properties)

```
const linda = await Actor
  .query()
  .findOne({ name: 'Linda Hamilton' });

.
.
.

await linda
  .$relatedQuery('movies')
  .patch({ characterName: 'Florence' })
  .where('movies.name', 'Curvature')
```

In a method somewhere, I do the following

```
// At some point above, I do a query().findOne to get the waitlist
// trx is a transaction object
// id is the id of the user I want to update the rank of
        await waitlist
          .$relatedQuery('users', trx)
          .patch({ rank: targetRank })
          .where({ id })
```

This is a very dumbed down view of the migration

```
  return knex.schema
    .createTable('users', (table) => {
      table
        .uuid('id')
        .primary()
        .notNullable()
      table.timestamp('createdAt').defaultTo(knex.fn.now())
      table.timestamp('updatedAt').defaultTo(knex.fn.now())
    })
    .createTable('waitlists', (table) => {
      table
        .uuid('id')
        .primary()
        .notNullable()
      table.timestamp('createdAt').defaultTo(knex.fn.now())
      table.timestamp('updatedAt').defaultTo(knex.fn.now())
    })
    .createTable('waitlists_users', (table) => {
      table.uuid('waitlistId')
      table
        .foreign('waitlistId')
        .references('id')
        .inTable('waitlists')
        .onDelete('CASCADE')
      table.uuid('userId')
      table
        .foreign('userId')
        .references('id')
        .inTable('users')
        .onDelete('CASCADE')
      table.primary(['waitlistId', 'userId'])
      table.integer('rank').index()
    })
```

And finally the waitlist model definition, not providing users since this should be completely transparent to that model, it does not care about it's rank changing

```
  static tableName = 'waitlists'

  static jsonSchema = {
    type: 'object',
    required: [],
    properties: {},
  }

  static get relationMappings() {
    const UserModel = require('where/the/model/is/at').default

    return {
      users: {
        relation: ObjectionModel.ManyToManyRelation,
        modelClass: UserModel,
        join: {
          from: 'waitlists.id',
          through: {
            from: 'waitlists_users.waitlistId',
            to: 'waitlists_users.userId',
            extra: ['rank'],
          },
          to: 'users.id',
        },
      },
    }
  }
```

Executing that tiny patch query above results in this

```
ValidationError: rank: is an invalid additional property
      at Function.createValidationError (node_modules/objection/lib/model/Model.js:397:12)
      at parseValidationError (node_modules/objection/lib/model/AjvValidator.js:189:21)
      at AjvValidator.validate (node_modules/objection/lib/model/AjvValidator.js:78:19)
      at validate (node_modules/objection/lib/model/modelValidate.js:35:20)
      at UserModel.$validate (node_modules/objection/lib/model/Model.js:133:12)
      at setJson (node_modules/objection/lib/model/modelSet.js:28:16)
      at UserModel.$setJson (node_modules/objection/lib/model/Model.js:171:12)
      at Function.fromJson (node_modules/objection/lib/model/Model.js:320:11)
      at Function.ensureModel (node_modules/objection/lib/model/Model.js:630:25)
      at ManyToManyUpdateOperation.onAdd (node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/operations/UpdateOperation.js:22:29)
      at ManyToManyUpdateOperation.onAdd (node_modules/objection/lib/relations/manyToMany/update/ManyToManyUpdateOperationBase.js:28:23)
      at QueryBuilder.callOperationMethod (node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilderOperationSupport.js:345:33)
      at QueryBuilder.addOperationUsingMethod (node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilderOperationSupport.js:381:28)
      at QueryBuilder.addOperation (node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilderOperationSupport.js:372:22)
      at writeOperation (node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:890:12)
      at writeOperation (node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:1465:5)
```

NOTE: I have not gone down the raw approach, but that will only be a last resort

EDIT: For clarification, anything that seems dummy is because it is, I removed most of the baggage (like model properties and methods) from the post, let me know if those are required. The user Schema and the waitlist schema are both fully developed and functional, they can be used for crud cleanly. What I wish for is to be able to patch the join table rows given a waitlist, an user and a target rank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json schema must include `rank` property or you need to allow additional properties or remove that dummy schema all together.

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.5.6

```
  static jsonSchema = {
    type: 'object',
    required: [],
    properties: {},
    additionalProperties: true
  }
```

Comment: This was right, I did not think the user Schema would ever be read for an operation changing the join table. Adding the rank prop to the schema worked, even though users by themselves have no rank

Comment: I don't know if that feature is intentional, but kind of makes sense, since that extra property `rank` is declared in `waitlists` model. Also knowing in which stage json schema validation is done it also makes sense.